# Create only linkdb in apache nutch

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am using apache nutch version 1.7 to crawl the internet. Everything works fine. However, I am interested in inlinks and outlinks as all what I do is link analysis. So I am **not** interested in content, parse text etc. How can I instruct nutch only to build the linkdb? but not others (crawldb or segmentdb) as I am not interested in html content. Is there an option to automatically purge crawldb and segmentdb while crawling). I am doing a large scale crawling in the internet and need to be very space efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The details of limiting the crawl content is given in http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/class/Seminar/Pagerank/nutch/nutch.html

You can use the following configuration property in nutch site config

```
<property>
  <name>fetcher.store.content</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>If true, fetcher will store content.</description>
</property>
```

Please note that if you set this in the initial crawl, no content will be generated hence no links and fetcher will fail half way saying that it doesndoes not have segment content.

Comment: Mind updating that link? It's no longer valid.